# How the software company manages different version of Programs?

Tags: debugging, software-distribution

Most of the software company have old software which continue maintain, and they also develop current / new software. How they manage different versions of program? Is there any tools to help developers maintain software version? thz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, people use what is called [software configuration management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management) software, which usually includes a [version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_Control) like Subversion, Mercurial, git, Visual SourceSafe, et cetera and a [project management suite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_management) such as Trac, Bugzilla, Google Code, SourceForge and the like.  There are about a million options here.

Personally, I'm a big fan of the Mercurial and Trac combination, but lots of people live by Subversion (and people love git, too).

Answer (score 0):

We use subversion with branching/tagging.

Answer (score 0):

The use a tool called "version control system" or VCS. It allows to keep a history of all changes, give certain points in time a name (like "release 1.0") and to create branches (one for maintenance and one for the next version).

Today, you should have a look at Mercurial or [Git](http://git-scm.com/). For an introduction to Mercurial, see [hginit.com](http://hginit.com).

All other tools are very expensive (either in terms of your time or your money or both).